# C++ default arguments can break calling code - how to mitigate?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

Disclaimer: I am not a C++ developer, but I hack at a C++ project as a hobby. My question is about understanding some of C++'s design choices and how to manage them as a developer. Note that the project is old and not originally written by me, I just hack it for fun.

Consider the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int addNums(double a, double b)
{
    cout << "addNums impl 1\n";
    return a+b;
}

int addNums(int a, int b, int c)
{
    cout << "addNums impl 2\n";
    return a+b+c;
}

int main()
{
    addNums(1,2);
    return 0;
}
```

When run, it produces the output "addNums impl 1". But if I now modify the program slightly:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int addNums(double a, double b)
{
    cout << "addNums impl 1\n";
    return a+b;
}

int addNums(int a, int b, int c = 2)
{
    cout << "addNums impl 2\n";
    return a+b+c;
}

int main()
{
    addNums(1,2);
    return 0;
}
```

It produces the output "addNums impl 2" and the return value of `addNums(1,2)` has changed (in the first program it's 3, and in the second program it's 5). If we assume the `addNums` functions are in a library somewhere, and the `main` part of the program is written by a different person, then the author of the `main` program has no real way to know what's happened.

In this trivial example it's easy to see what happened, however a similar thing happened with `std::string::insert` which is distributed as part of gcc: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/insert/

Notice in C++11 the second implementation is `string& insert (size_t pos, const string& str, size_t subpos, size_t sublen);` and then in C++14 the implementation added a default argument to sublen: `string& insert (size_t pos, const string& str, size_t subpos, size_t sublen = npos);`. As with the trivial example above, programs calling `insert` with 3 arguments may now suddenly get a different implementation to before. And this different implementation has significantly different behaviour.

As a concrete example, In the project I was working on, some code combines two paths: one is a mount point looks like "/some/mount/" and the other is a path like "/some/path/" with the goal of producing "/some/mount/some/path/". The code uses [CStdString.h](https://github.com/lunakid/CStdString/blob/master/CStdString.h). A drastically simplified version of it is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "CStdString.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    CStdString cSpath = "/some/path/";
    CStdString cSmount = "/some/mount/";
    cSpath.insert(0, cSmount, cSmount.size()-1);

    cout<<cSpath.c_str();

    return 0;
}
```

I compile this code using: `g++ test.cpp -o test`. When this code is compiled using a version of GCC older than 9.1.0, the output is `/some/mount/some/path/` but on newer versions the output is `//some/path/`. i.e., before the default parameter was added, the compiler used an implementation of `insert` where the 3rd argument represents how many characters from the start of the input string (argument 2) to insert, and the newer version of library causes the compiler to use an implementation where the 3rd argument represents the *start position* of the input string to insert from. The compiler doesn't give any warnings or errors about this potentially unwanted implementation being used. I tracked the change to [this commit](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/852ee53c2775b43fef0) in GCC.

My question is, as someone writing or looking at C++ code, how am I supposed to mitigate this kind of thing? It's almost impossible (for someone naive like myself) to figure out why the behvaiour of the program has changed. It seems like GCC has made a breaking backwards incompatible change, and as a developer I have no way to know about it. Are there tools and techniques that seasoned C++ developers use to avoid these problems? If so, what are they?

Comment: One could wax lyrical on the pros and cons of combining overloaded functions with default arguments; as also on the whys and wherefores of the implementation of the Standard Library. But I'm not sure Stack Overflow is really the place to do this.

Comment: I'm not concerned about the pros and cons of it. I'm more interested in how I as a developer can discover these changes. For example, can I get the compiler to warn me about what's going on?

Comment: Even without default argument, adding an extra overload might become a better match.

Comment: Adding an extra overload where?

Comment: instead of `int addNums(int a, int b, int c = 2)`, `int addNums(int a, int b) {/*impl3*/}` would be a better match for your first example.

Comment: The first example was just to demonstrate the problem that I saw happen in a real world project. The issue that affected the project I was working on was in the standard library, where I can't (well, shouldn't) add more overloads.

Comment: The second test program provides an example of that. You'll need to look at CStdString.h (sorry I don't really know much about how that lib works, just that the project I was working on uses it).

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know. All I  know for sure is that the code ends up calling the `insert` functions from this library file: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h

Comment: Just to clarify, the project I hack at is not something I originally wrote. I've updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: It is generally unsupported to derive from standard classes, in the sense that while the C++ committee (which is what's actually in charge of `std::string`, not the GCC devs...) are careful to avoid breaking changes in most use cases, they won't protect you if you're deriving from their classes. `cSpath.insert(0, cSmount, cSmount.size() - 1)` is simply illegal before C++14 when using `std::string` (which is *why* they felt safe adding the default). The blame is in `CStdString` for deriving `std::string` and adding `operator const char*()`. (There was a *reason* it wasn't there originally!)

Comment: I see where the problem comes from now. It's caused by implicit conversion of `CStdString` to `const char*` (https://github.com/lunakid/CStdString/blob/master/CStdString.h#L3779). Such an implicit conversion is quite bad practice IMO, it can make problems at many different situations. Note that it may be suppressed by defining `SS_NO_IMPLICIT_CAST` macro symbol before `CStdString.h` header is included.

Comment: "`typedef CStdStr<char>  CStdStringA; // a better std::string`" is a bold claim

Comment: Do not use cplusplus.com to reason about anything as it is vague and does not often list all changes. See how cppreference https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert is lot more complete.

Comment: @HTNW I think especially that they inherited publicly from `std::string` is a problem. Had they inherited privately and replicated the interface they want, then this wouldn't have been a problem either. The implicit conversion to `char*` might be bad by itself, but they could have made it compatible and stable with their interface. With `public` inheritance they basically assume that future changes of `std::string`'s interface will be compatible with their modifications to the interface.

Comment: Anything that implicitly converts to both `const char *` *and* `std::string` is problematic, because there's a whole load of functions that will be overloaded on `std::string`, and `const char *, std::size_t`.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments, I was able to use them to dig deeper and fully understand the problem and I agree, it's nothing to do with GCC or C++, the problem mainly lies in this library that is abusing features of the language.

Comment: @DanielLangr and (and HTNW but I can't tag two people) your answers in particular were very helpful, if you'd like to post something like that in answer format I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: @CameronBall My comment actually does not answer your question. Even though it is useful for your particular case, I don't think it should be turned into an answer for this post. You are asking about the generic issue and my comment is related to just that particular exemplary case with `CStdString`.

Answer (score 3):

> as someone writing or looking at C++ code, how am I supposed to mitigate this kind of thing? It's almost impossible (for someone naive like myself) to figure out why the behvaiour of the program has changed.

You write unit tests, and you'll know pretty fast the behaviour has changed.

As with all dependencies, upgrading, which necessitates accepting API changes and possible bugs, is not a trivial task. This is why you treat dependencies as a first-class design problem and not as an afterthought.